# MongoDB Aggregation - Get all distinct layers from a category tree and merge into another collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a product list and each product has it's category, for example `>technology>televisions>4k>`.

I need to get all distinct categories, from those I need to create each distinct category layer and merge it into another collection.

What I would need to end up with is

`>technology>`
`>technology>televisions>`
`>technology>televisions>4k>`

Bear in mind, there is no product with category `>technology>`, meaning I have to use `$split` or something to generate the layers that do not have products too.

I have no problem getting all distinct categories from the product using `$group` aggregation pipeline stage and I would use `$merge` to insert them into another collection, but I do not know how to generate distinct categories that do not have a product.

What I did was, generated an array from the category using `$project`, `$filter` and `$split`:

INPUT: `{ '_id': '>technology>televisions>4k>' }`

```
  _id: {
    split: {
      $filter: 
      {
        input: {$split: ["$_id", ">"] },
        as: "categories",
        cond: {
          "$ne": [ "$$categories", "" ]
        }
      }
      
    }
  }
```

Which would get me the list of `['technology', 'televisions', '4k']` from `>technology>televisions>4k>`, but again the final result I need is

`>technology>`
`>technology>televisions>`
`>technology>televisions>4k>`

Comment: can you add some sample input and output documents

Comment: I have added the input right before the aggregation pipeline stage, but it was there already.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly, you will need to map the array of elements, with a running concatenation of all elements up to the current element, like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      categories: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $split: [
              "$_id",
              ">"
            ]
          },
          as: "categories",
          cond: {
            "$ne": [
              "$$categories",
              ""
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      categories: {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(categories) { let start = '>'; return categories.map(category => {start = start + category + '>'; return start})} ",
          "args": [
            "$categories"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here's the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pEfiwRUVQBm).

Comment: `$function` is something that I feel like I should avoid due to it's performance. There must be a better way of doing it, but thanks for the effort. By the way the result is correct

Comment: Sure, but if it's a one-time operation. It can be used.